# Using constants as state names in angular

Tags: angularjs, routes, angular-ui-router

We are building an angular app and using the ui router.

States are defined as usual:

`$stateProvider.state("home.newest", {});`

But then we must use an arbitrary string to go to the state like this:

`$state.go("home.newest", ...);`

What is the proper way to define and use constants so we could do something like this?

`$state.go(consts.STATE_HOME_NEWEST, ...);`

I looked around and this doesnt seem to be common practice. Am i missing something?

Thanks :)

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/angular.Module#constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a "constant file" to do so. Once this file create, you will have to inject it where you need it.

There is the file with your state reference :

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.constant("state", {
    STATE_HOME_NEWEST: "...."
    //What you want
});
```

Then, you will have to inject "state" this like anything else and you will be able to retreive data with :

```
state.STATE_HOME_NEWEST
```